# Dynamic array in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have created an packaged object (TMyComponent) of TLabel and TCombobox in delphi 7.
I have  created an dynamic array(MyArray) of TMyComponent. Now on Add button click I have increamented length of MyArray and create  object of TLabel and TCombobox and displayed on screen. If I have added 5 components, How we can get current selected component of Myaaray means if i selected 3rd component from screen then how can i get value 3 in return?  thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a function like this:

```
function FindMyComponentIndex(
  Selected: TMyComponent; 
  const Components: array of TMyComponent
): Integer;
begin
  for Result := low(Components) to high(Components) do 
    if Components[Result]=Selected then
      exit;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

I trust it will be obvious how to call this function.

Comment: thanks david. i will try it. Can we pass integer value in OnSelect event of TComboBox?

Comment: I don't understand that question

Comment: Onselect event of TCombobox have parameters (Sender:TObject). can we pass any other parameter along with Sender?

Comment: You can't change parameter lists for built in events. You could read information out of sender perhaps.

Comment: @naren you should post another question, however you could do a cast on the sender and use Tag property to store an integer value, i.e. TComboBox(Sender).Tag